# How do you make a Discord bot reply to a certain message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, replit

Code:

```
async def on_message(message):
  if client.user.mentioned_in(message) and client.user in message.mentions:

    if message.author.bot:
      return

    if message.content.startswith("!!") and message.content.endswith("/"):
      if message.content.startswith("!!reply/"):
        # ???
```

I'm trying to make the bot reply to a message. You can send the message ID to the bot and the bot saves the message ID as a variable, then replies to the correct message using its message ID. I don't really know where to start here. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

First, use the `@client.event` decorator on your `on_message` function to allow your bot to receive messages. (Also remember to enable message_content intent)

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    …
```

or you can set “!!” as your command prefix and use a command (this uses discord.ext.commands.Bot)

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=“!!”, …)

@bot.command(name=“reply”)
async def reply_command(ctx, message_id):
    …
```

I will use the on_message example for your reply function.
Your bot receives the message id as an argument. Using `channel.fetch_message`, you can get the message object you want to reply to.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith(“!!”):
        split_message = message.content.split() # [“!!reply”, “messageid”]
        if split_message[0] == “!!reply”:
            message_id = int(split_message[1]) # message.content is a str
            reply_to = await message.channel.fetch_message(message_id)
            await reply_to.reply(“Hello World!”)
```

After getting the message object, you can simply reply to it.

Here, splitting the message gets the arguments of the command. `.split()` would split the message from “Hello World!” to a list [“Hello”, “World!”]. So the first argument would be a command “!!reply” and the second would be the message id.

[General documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76494482/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-fetch-message/