# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetch_message'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

Code snippet:

```
async def ping_start(msg, target_channel_id, target_message_id):
              if msg == "floodfrightcmd":
                msg = "!!floodfrightbuttons/"
              print("Entered async ping start")
              global automatecmd
              global automateDebounce
              print(automatecmd)
              print(target_channel_id)
              target_channel = client.get_channel(target_channel_id)
              print(target_message_id)
              target_message = await target_channel.fetch_message(target_message_id)
```

For some reason, *target_channel* is returning with nothing. I can't tell why this is the case. When printed, *target_channel_id* was the correct channel ID and target_message_id was the correct message ID.

I also tried replacing  `target_channel = client.get_channel(target_channel_id)` with `target_channel = client.get_guild(1043374167967408161).get_channel(target_channel_id)`, but it still wouldn't work and would show the same error.

How would I fix this?

I also have all privileged gateway intents enabled in the developer portal and have this at the beginning of my script.

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.reactions = True
intents.members = True
intents.guilds = True
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65789837/dicord-py-get-channel-returns-none

Comment: Make sure `target_channel_id` is not a string. Have you tried parsing your channel id directly into `guild.get_channel()` then performing an action like print or send?

Comment: OHHHH, it was a string not an int, ty!

Answer (score 0):

If the target_channel and client values are correct and properly initialized, then this could be a permissions issue. Are you sure that the code is setting the correct permissions to fetch the messages?

Comment: I turned on all the privileged gateway intents in the developer portal and have this at the beginning of my script: (check OP, edited it)